# Julia run/pipeline command translation

Tags: unix, command, line, julia

I'm having some trouble with the run/pipeline commands and I'm not exactly sure where I'm going wrong. My goal is to append to a log and redirect STDERR so that errors will be in the log. The command line equivalent of what I want to run (which works when run at the terminal) is the following:

```
/home/me/juliaScripts/runjob.jl $three $one $one >> /home/me/dailylog.txt 2>&1
```

what I'm doing in Julia:

```
runstring=`/home/me/juliaScripts/runjob.jl $three $one $one`
run(pipeline(runstring,stdout="/home/me/dailylog.txt",stderr="/home/me/dailylog.txt",append=true))
```

The error I'm getting is : ERROR: pipeline not defined
Is there a better way to use the run command to achieve what I want (appending to a log and redirecting STDERR)? Thanks so much.

Comment: just realized pipeline function not available on my .3.8 version of Julia....does anyone know a work around for earlier versions of Julia?

Answer (score 3):

There is a meta solution for running the equivalent of a shell command and it is to run it in a shell. For the example given:

```
bashcmd = "/home/me/juliaScripts/runjob.jl $three $one $one >> /home/me/dailylog.txt 2>&1"
run(`/bin/bash -c $bashcmd`)
```

This should work in version 0.3, but the `/bin/bash` may need to be replaced with a different path (depending on the shell you are running). Additionally, the `$three $one $one` need to be more carefully escaped (if they are simple alphanumeric words it should be OK).

Answer (score 1):

The `pipeline` command was introduced in version 0.4 of Julia. 
If you are not using 0.4, I suggest you upgrade. (There is also no problem in having two versions of Julia installed side-by-side.)

Comment: unfortunately that's not an option at the moment. I can work around everything except the 2>&1. Any idea how translate that into Julia with backticks and/or other operators?

Comment: I had to fiddle a ton with the quoting to get something similar working.  Mine looks like:

    readall(`$pathtobin arg1=makewidgets 'source='$sourcefile '/output='$resultsfile /format=png`)

    readall(`reg query 'HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Someone\Product\Blah' /v BaseDirectory`)