# julia shell command tar and pigz

Tags: shell, command, julia, pipeline, external

I want to compress a folder in julia:

```sh
tar -cvf - "source" | pigz -k -9 > "source.tar.xz"
```

where `source` is a folder

I tried this in julia:

```
run(pipeline(`tar -cvf - "2001_ A Space Odyssey"` , `pigz -k -9 \> "2001_ A Space Odyssey.tar.xz"`))
```

but it didn't work. I got error below:

```
pigz: skipping: > does not exist
pigz: skipping: 2001_ A Space Odyssey.tar.xz does not exist
2001_ A Space Odyssey/
2001_ A Space Odyssey/cover.jpg
ERROR: LoadError: failed process: Process(`pigz -k -9 '>' '2001_ A Space Odyssey.tar.xz'`, ProcessExited(1)) [1]
```

How can I do it in julia?

Comment: This may help... https://stackoverflow.com/a/34093251/2836621

Comment: When Julia runs a command, it doesn't do any shell-like parsing -- once it interpolates variables, it blindly passes every argument to the command. In contrast, bash parses its input before evaluating, and when it sees a `>`, it parses it as a redirection (and same for `|`, `&&`, etc) before evaluating. In other words, `>` is shell syntax that doesn't exist in Julia; to achieve the same behavior, you pass arguments to `run`.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot use shell commands like `>` inside a Julia command, instead, you pass the file as an extra argument:

```
run(pipeline(`tar -cvf - "source"`, `pigz -k -9`, "source.tar.xz"))
```

Comment: Thank you! It works. But I am confused about something. I have also tried:
```julia
cmd = pipeline(`tar -cvf - "source"` |> `pigz -k -9` |> "source.tar.xz")
cmd = pipeline(`pigz -k -9`, stdin=`tar -cvf - "source"`, stdout=`"source.tar.xz"`)
```

Why those didn't work?

Comment: Remove the quotes around the file in the `stdout` keyword argument.